# How to index and search array in solr with PHP

Tags: php, solr, cakephp-2.0, solr4

In our CakePHP application, we have an array like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [org_id] => 1
                    [name] => Troubadour
                    [url_seo] => think-alone
                    [description] => Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. 
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [sub_category_id] => 1
                    [special_offer] => yes
                    [capacity] => 100
                    [visibility] => E
                    [location] => Old National Centre     502 North New Jersey St Indianapolis, IN, 46204
                    [address] => Old National Centre      502 North New Jersey St Indianapolis, IN, 46204
                    [city] => Indianapolis
                    [state] => WA
                    [country] => US
                    [zipcode] => 98828 
                    [fb_url] => https://www.facebook.com/Think Alone
                    [twitter_url] => https://www.twitter.com/Think Alone
                    [status] => A
                    [featured] => Y
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [Organization] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [name] =>  test org
                    [company_profile] => We are a company built on integrity
                    [motto] => Engineering Knowledge
                    [logo] => 
                    [website] => http://www. test org.com/
                    [subdomain] => 
                    [timezone] => 
                    [currency] => 
                    [video_link] => 
                    [company_email] => info@ test org.com
                    [contact_address] =>  test org Technologies. 4th and 5th floor,  Asset Iris Building, N F Gate Main Road, Tripunithura, Cochin,  India    - 682 301
                    [contact_phone] => + 91 484 2785 833
                    [contact_mobile] => 
                    [city] => Cochin
                    [state] => Ernakulam
                    [country] => india
                    [zipcode] => 682 301
                    [email_notification] => 1
                    [fb_url] => https://www.facebook.com/ test org
                    [twitter_url] => https://www.twitter.com/ test org
                    [status] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [name] => Business
                    [image] => 
                    [category_code] => business
                    [status] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [SubCategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [category_id] => 1
                    [name] => Advertising & Marketing 
                    [image] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [EventDate] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [start_date] => 2013-09-21
                            [start_time] => 10:00:00
                            [start_session] => A
                            [end_date] => 2013-09-22
                            [end_time] => 5:00:00
                            [end_session] => P
                            [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 9
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [start_date] => 2013-09-23
                            [start_time] => 10:00:00
                            [start_session] => A
                            [end_date] => 2013-09-24
                            [end_time] => 5:00:00
                            [end_session] => P
                            [created] => 2013-09-19 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-19 00:00:00
                        )

                    [2] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 7
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [start_date] => 2013-09-27
                            [start_time] => 10:00:00
                            [start_session] => A
                            [end_date] => 2013-09-28
                            [end_time] => 5:00:00
                            [end_session] => P
                            [created] => 2013-09-18 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-18 00:00:00
                        )

                    [3] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 14
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [start_date] => 2013-09-29
                            [start_time] => 10:00:00
                            [start_session] => A
                            [end_date] => 2013-09-30
                            [end_time] => 5:00:00
                            [end_session] => P
                            [created] => 2013-09-25 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-25 00:00:00
                        )

                    [4] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [start_date] => 2013-10-15
                            [start_time] => 10:00:00
                            [start_session] => A
                            [end_date] => 2013-10-15
                            [end_time] => 5:00:00
                            [end_session] => P
                            [created] => 2013-09-18 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-18 00:00:00
                        )

                )

            [EventMedia] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [image_url] => upcom-img1.jpg
                            [video_url] => 
                            [created] => 2013-09-25 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-25 00:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 6
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [image_url] => upcom-img4.jpg
                            [video_url] => 
                            [created] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 0000-00-00 00:00:00
                        )

                )

            [EventTicket] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 1
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [name] => VIP Early Bird Experience
                            [inventory] => 60
                            [pricing] => P
                            [price] => 30
                            [more_info] => It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable Eng
                            [sale_start_date] => 2013-09-15
                            [sale_start_time] => 10.00 AM
                            [sale_end_date] => 2013-09-20
                            [sale_end_time] => 5.00 PM
                            [min_tickets_per_order] => 1
                            [max_tickets_per_order] => 1
                            [ticket_series] => 1_1000
                            [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                        )

                    [1] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 2
                            [event_id] => 1
                            [name] => Craft Beer Heaven
                            [inventory] => 40
                            [pricing] => P
                            [price] => 20
                            [more_info] => It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content here, content here', making it look like readable Eng
                            [sale_start_date] => 2013-09-16
                            [sale_start_time] => 10.00 AM
                            [sale_end_date] => 2013-09-20
                            [sale_end_time] => 5.00 PM
                            [min_tickets_per_order] => 1
                            [max_tickets_per_order] => 1
                            [ticket_series] => 1_1061
                            [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                            [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                        )

                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [Event] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 10
                    [org_id] => 1
                    [name] => Music Night
                    [url_seo] => music-night
                    [description] => Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. 
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [sub_category_id] => 3
                    [special_offer] => no
                    [capacity] => 30
                    [visibility] => E
                    [location] => Los Angeles
                    [address] => The Echo     1822 W Sunset Blvd Los Angeles, California, 90026
                    [city] => Los Angeles
                    [state] => California
                    [country] => US
                    [zipcode] => 90026
                    [fb_url] => http://www.facebook.com/music-night
                    [twitter_url] => http://www.twitter.com/music-night
                    [status] => A
                    [featured] => N
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [Organization] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [user_id] => 2
                    [name] =>  test org
                    [company_profile] => We are a company built on integrity
                    [motto] => Engineering Knowledge
                    [logo] => 
                    [website] => http://www. test org.com/
                    [subdomain] => 
                    [timezone] => 
                    [currency] => 
                    [video_link] => 
                    [company_email] => info@ test org.com
                    [contact_address] =>  test org Technologies. 4th and 5th floor,  Asset Iris Building, N F Gate Main Road, Tripunithura, Cochin,  India    - 682 301
                    [contact_phone] => + 91 484 2785 833
                    [contact_mobile] => 
                    [city] => Cochin
                    [state] => Ernakulam
                    [country] => india
                    [zipcode] => 682 301
                    [email_notification] => 1
                    [fb_url] => https://www.facebook.com/ test org
                    [twitter_url] => https://www.twitter.com/ test org
                    [status] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [Category] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [name] => Music & nightlife
                    [image] => 
                    [category_code] => music
                    [status] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [SubCategory] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 3
                    [category_id] => 2
                    [name] => music sub1
                    [image] => 
                    [status] => 1
                    [created] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                    [modified] => 2013-09-13 00:00:00
                )

            [EventDate] => Array
                (
                )

            [EventMedia] => Array
                (
                )

            [EventTicket] => Array
                (
                )

        )

)
```

We want to index this array and want to search the events with event-name, organization-name, event-city etc....

What we do ?

We are very new in Solr and we are currently using SolrPhpClient for this,  but based on this array it become very difficult....

All helps are appreciated....

**UPDATE**

---

We have a cakephp apllication, in that there have search fetaure. So we want to integrate Apache solr for searching...

This is the tutorial we followed :

```
http://www.webdesignermag.co.uk/tutorials/how-to-add-search-with-solr/
```

Bu its for Pure php , we need to integrate it in cakephp.

How can we do this?

According to the above tutorial, there need to first index the all data and records before searching....

So the above array is our all data now..

When we enter the searching text as `Troubadour` and city as `Indianapolis` , then the searching condition will be below:

```
( Event.name = Troubadour OR Event.location = Troubadour OR Organization.name = Troubadour) AND Event.city = Indianapolis
```

This is our scenario....

Anyboady help me...Its wasting my 3 day and still.....

Comment: please explain clearly what you want in this array?

Comment: @NathanSrivi, Please check my updates......

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can't filter the data directly in your DataBase and that you have to filter the resulting array (but please, explain us why you can't), cakephp let you extract filtered data from the array like this:

```
$filteredArray = Hash::extract($array, '{n}.Event[name=Troubadour]');
```

see [CakePHP Hash](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-utility-libraries/hash.html)

hope this answer your question